# How can I shift game which is getting download to another system in Steam?

Tags: steam

Here is the brief of situation I am currently in right now,I have bought Raibow Six siege on Steam and I have downloaded 5 Gb of 21 Gb,but then I realized I could have downloaded that in my laptop and could have played BF4 in my main PC,because of multiple internet I have at my home.

So is this possible to shift that 5gb segment to other system and resume it from there?

Answer (score 2):

Steam doesn't support peer downloads itself but you can try copying over the data in the `steamapps/common` folder and restarting the download.